# how to alternate matches between positive lookbehind and ahead using regex?

Tags: html, regex

I have a regex: `(?<=>).*?(?=<)` which properly matches text from my html. It's probably simplified query but doesn't matter.

My question is: how to modify this query to match all except some word?

What I'm trying to do is `(?<=>).*?(?!ICMJE)(?=<)` to skip this word, but it doesn't work as many of my trials.

The html snippet looks like:

```
<th class="header3 banner_color" align="left" valign="top" width="15%">Intervention <sup style="color:blue"> ICMJE </sup>
</th>
```

Finally match should return only one "Intervention" word. Please help.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. I was close.

Comment: you can use [`(?<=>)((?!ICMJE).)*(?=<)`](https://regex101.com/r/AhLwss/3) a more precise version

Comment: Both of your versions works fine, however, I can't find a difference between them. For large html I've got 136 and 163 matches respectively.

Comment: the first one will find a match if there is no space because `.` before the negative lookahead will give you  [`ICMJE as a match`](https://regex101.com/r/JKJJIG/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative look-ahead [`(?<=>)((?!ICMJE).)*(?=<)`](https://regex101.com/r/VL6pxT/1)

which will match anything except your string

`(?<=>)((?!ICMJE).)*(?=<)` :

- `(?<=>)` : positive -look behind to match `>` character
- `((?!ICMJE).)` match anything till line-break except `ICMJE`
- `(?=<)` positive look-ahead to match `<` characterr

Comment: Ok great. So developing this idea, it'd be well for further extends to write :`(?<=>)((?!ICMJE|Type).)*(?=<)` for excluding some other word, right? Or rather that group which contains this word.

Comment: yes you can , although i won't recommend to use more words because this won't be a very quick process for many words

Comment: Sorry. I've found a little bug in this pattern. Adding one ? is better, when there is some nested <...> within the match. For example: <td class="body3" valign="top">Effectiveness and Safety of 3 Dosing Regimens of CP-690,550 to Placebo in Subjects With Moderate to Severe Chronic Plaque <span class="hit_inf">Psoriasis</span>
</td>. My code is: `(?<=>)((?!ICMJE).)*?(?=<)` Check and update. It works similarly to the source idea.

Comment: @Peter.k actually `*` works as greedy so by doing `*?` you are making it non-greedy mean match as less as possible although it's great that you solved it on you own , happy coding